# Getting Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when there is no records in the table

Tags: php, mysqli, codeigniter-3

I have two tables with records. In the first table, I am displaying personal information and in the second table, I am adding the activities details.

Now I am trying to display the record using joins. So below code, I am using in the model

```
public function getMemberActivity($gotMemberId){
$getDetails = array('members.member_id'=>$gotMemberId,'member_activity.activity_status'=>1,'members.is_Approved'=>1);
$result = $this->db->where($getDetails)
 ->from('members')
 ->join('member_activity', 'members.member_id = member_activity.member_id','LEFT')
 ->get()
 ->result();
//echo $this->db->last_query();
//print_r($result);
    if($result)
    {
         return $result;  
    }
    else 
    {
       return 0;  
    }

  }
```

**Controller**

**Note: I am getting multiple member id here because I have above some more logic. that's the reason I am using for each.**

```
$ActivityData=[];
foreach ($data['getAllMember'] as $key => $m_id) {
$ActivityData[] = $this->Access_model->getMemberActivity($m_id->member_id);
   }
$data['MemberActivity'] = $ActivityData;
```

Now If I found the records related the member id in the secondary table then I am getting the output but if not found a record in the second table then I am getting the error `Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

If I remove `'member_activity.activity_status'=>1` from the `where` clause then my join query is working. I mean I am getting the member records.

```
 ->join('member_activity', 'members.member_id = member_activity.member_id','LEFT')
```

**View**

```
$SActivity=$MemberActivity; 

//print_r($SActivity);
if($SActivity){

  foreach ($SActivity as $sec_1) {

  foreach ($sec_1 as $sec_activities) {
     //list here

  }

}

}
else{echo"no data availalbe";}
```

So my expected output is, I have to display the records if found in the second table if not found then also display the member table records.

Would you help me out in this?

Comment: this seems to be the issue with your logic, as far as i can understand in both the cases you want to display the data?... if that is the case... why are you not putting  both the foreach in the else condition? ... you debug your query for both condition, I believe you are getting different shape and structure for "not found" condition, hence the output

Comment: Which `foreach` making problem here `foreach ($data['getAllMember'] as $key => $m_id)` or `foreach` inside `View`?

Comment: @BILALMALIK, Yes, you are correct, both the cases you want to display the data. If data available in the second table then display the records if not available then display first table records........... This is not working if I remove 'member_activity.activity_status'=>1 from the where clause

Comment: foreach ($data['getAllMember'] as $key => $m_id) this doesnt seems to be the problem....... it must be the view,  perhaps you dont event need if else condition in view if all you want is a data in both the condition,,,

Comment: @BILALMALIK, Ok, I will remove it. if conditions. any more help in this?

Comment: Guys below have actually posted answer for you, does it not work as you like?... write those code in your controller and return the data in view, it should work

Comment: use an if(count()) check before the foreach loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your model function `getMemberActivity`. If there is no record then you returns `0` and when you `foreach` you will get error because its not an array. So you can simply return `$result` since codeigniter return default array.

```
public function getMemberActivity($gotMemberId)
{
    $getDetails = array('members.member_id' => $gotMemberId, 'members.is_Approved' => 1);
    $result = $this->db->where($getDetails)
        ->from('members')
        ->join('member_activity', 'members.member_id = member_activity.member_id AND member_activity.activity_status = 1', 'LEFT')
        ->get()
        ->result();
    return $result;

}
```

Second option is you can check `!empty` before your `foreach`.

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: Yes, the error goes off, Now I am getting the records which are available. Is it possible to display the first table records if not available in the second table?

Comment: Can you check now. I have updated the answer. The where condition `member_activity.activity_status` is moved to `join`.

Answer (score 2):

Move your where condition `'member_activity.activity_status'=>1` in `JOIN` as below,

```
$public function getMemberActivity($gotMemberId){
$getDetails = array('members.member_id'=>$gotMemberId,'members.is_Approved'=>1);
$result = $this->db->where($getDetails)
 ->from('members')
 ->join('member_activity', 'members.member_id = member_activity.member_id AND member_activity.activity_status = 1','LEFT')
 ->get()
 ->result();
//echo $this->db->last_query();
//print_r($result);
    if($result)
    {
         return $result;  
    }
    else 
    {
       return 0;  
    }

  }
```

Hope this will be help you.

Final query like this:

```
SELECT members.*,member_activity.* FROM members LEFT JOIN member_activity ON members.member_id = member_activity.member_id AND member_activity.activity_status = 1 
WHERE 'members.member_id' = $gotMemberId AND 'members.is_Approved' = 1;
```

Comment: Give me some time to check

Comment: Your answer is also working. I accepted the user6838959  answer because of the description. But really appreciated your answer. Upvote from my side.

Comment: @user9437856 But I answered first. check time :) :) Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's correct. you added first but I accepted the answer because of description. and I understood well. I am so sorry about this.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you, try

```
foreach ($SActivity as $sec_1) {
    if (!empty($sec_1)):
        foreach ($sec_1 as $sec_activities) {
            //list here
            print_r($sec_activities);  
        }
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Give me some time to check